# Dajaxice & Dajax DEBUG=False

Tags: python, dajaxice, dajax

How can I turn off Dajaxproject alert 'Something goes wrong' ? Sometimes my dajax functions returns empty data, hence variables in html are None. It does suit me however dajax alert is displayed. I have heard there is DAJAXICE_EXCEPTION but I do not know how tu use it properly. What you would do, when the website is generaly finished?

Answer (score 0):

This is purely speculative, and I haven't tested this myself, but I think the place you want to look is in line 87 of dajaxice.core.js:

```
valid_http_responses: function(){
    return {200: null, 301: null, 302: null, 304: null}
}
```

The section which throws errors is in line 51:

```
    if(this.responseText == Dajaxice.EXCEPTION || !(this.status in Dajaxice.valid_http_responses())){
            error_callback();
    }
```

So maybe changing `valid_http_responses` to:

```
valid_http_responses: function(){
    return {200: null, 204: null, 301: null, 302: null, 304: null}
}
```

From Wikipedia:

```
204 No Content:
    The server successfully processed the request, but is not returning any content
```

Maybe that will fix your issue?